# Asp.net MVC Session timeout condition based handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

My MVC web application uses asp.net session management. Session has default timeout 20mins. On session timeout, user is redirected to the home page. My application uses SessionTimeout ActionFilterAttribute to handle session timeout.
SessionState is stored in server.

**Problem**:
Even if the session timout happens, when the user returns to a particular action method, I need to renew a session for that user and allow to continue instead of redirecting to home page.

I have tried to use the OnActionExecuting method in the SessionTimeout ActionFilterAttribute to identify the session timeout & if the action in the request is that particular action method, then allow the user to continue to that action.

But it seems to be not working. It just redirects the user to the Home page.
I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It's been a few years since I worked with anything session related, but isn't the session gone once it has timed out? Meaning you can't "renew" it. I would think you have two options. You could either extend the timeout in the config or you can create some sort of keep alive script that calls the server in intervals shorter than the timeout.

Comment: Whatever you have said about session expiry is correct, What I wanted to do is create a new session and associate the new session with the user and navigate to the action method which was requested instead of redirecting to home page, on session timeout. Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible without re-authenticating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

1. "Session cannot be renewed" once it has expired.
2. Instead of renewing the session, create a new session in the ActionFilters Attribute (SessionTimeout).

The solution for my problem is to create a new session and re-link it with the domain object/user so that the user can continue his journey. I have done this in my SessionTimeout ActionFilterAttribute, to create new session for only a particular request which has the particular controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

Session have bad problems like timeout and refresh not available, do authentication using forms authentication you can choose this [custom authentication sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)

Or Else use cookies

```
        HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
        // for remveing if already Exists adding new;
        Request.Cookies.Remove("MyCookie");
        if (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] == null)
        {

            MyCookie["id"] = id.ToString();
            Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            MyCookie["id"] = id.ToString();
            // Request.Cookies.Remove("MyCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Set(MyCookie);
        }

        // retries 
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["MyCookie"]["id"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Forms Authentication is not an option in my system.

Comment: ok If FormsAuthentication not a option for your problem you can use cookies.

Comment: Can you tell me how can cookies solve my problem ? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Hi Goku..  I updated the answer with cookies, I guess you can use it useful for your purpose..

Comment: thanks for your response Saneesh, but I fixed the problem using ActionFilter by just creating a new session and adding it to the context of my business object.